# How to translate the modern use of dutch term 'strippenkaart'

Tags: translation

Originally, in the Netherlands, a 'strippenkaart' (literally 'stripescard') was a paper card with stripes one could use to travel. Each stripe was equivalent to a certain distance. If you wanted to travel on a bus or on a tram, depending on the distance you were going (counted in zones), a date/time stamp was placed on a particular stripe.

Nowadays, the original 'strippenkaart' for bus and tram has been replaced by a chip card which can be used for all public transport, but the term 'strippenkaart' is still used.

I think it can be defined as follows:

> You pay in advance for as many products that are on the card, but you 
>   get a discount.

So, for example, if a coffee costs € 3,00 you can buy a 'strippenkaart' for 10 cups for € 25,50 (instead of € 30,-)

How would a card like that be called in English?

**Update**

I am **not** talking about some kind of chip card, which holds some value equivalent to money, which can also be used for purchasing other things. It's more like a piece of paper with boxes that can be checked every time a purchase is made.

Also, I am looking for a more general term that can be used for all kinds of products. So you could have a 'strippenkaart' for cups of coffee, or haircuts etc.

Comment: Thanks @Spork, but that question is more about a public transport card. I am looking for a more general term.

Comment: The term "strippenkaart" is not used more generally than for transportation in Dutch, why would you expect there to be a more general but closely related term to it in English? A "strippenkaart" for coffee is not something I've ever come across in Holland.

Comment: @Sander_P That question is not about public transportation cards—in fact, the asker makes it clear (in a comment) that he’s looking for a word that can be used for a similar card for a gym.

Comment: @Spork: if I google for 'koffie strippenkaart', I get over 26.000 results! And that's just for coffee :)

Comment: @Sander_P and when you google for "koffie strippenkaart" you get 250 results. Significant, yes, but......

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: you are correct! I have now read all the comments including the ones that aren't show immediately. Still the accepted answer to that question suggests a therm only used for (a booklet of) train tickets in the UK.

Comment: @Spork And when you Google _koffiestrippenkaart_, you still get 73 results. For the record: the Scandinavian equivalents of what was originally a public transportation ticket type have also been expanded to be used for things like coffee and pizza. 7-Eleven in Denmark, for instance, advertise that they sell _kaffeklippekort_, and it’s quite common to have them in cafés as well. But the word _kaffeklippekort_ only yields 93 hits, which isn’t a significantly higher number than the Dutch version.

Comment: Generally speaking, this would be called a "pass" in the US.  The term can be used for any sort of document which gains admission or provides passage.  The pass may be of an infinite-use variety (expiring only by date, if at all), or may carry a designated number of miles/rides/credits which are somehow deducted on use.

Comment: In London it's called  an [**Oyster card**](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/oyster/what-is-oyster). In Dublin it's called a [**Leap card**](https://www.leapcard.ie/en/PageSetting/ContentViewer.aspx?Val=ZBrekG8wfXkh9SLJSHbw6noFkIk75Qi6k1aPi1ZmXTxiFP%2Bej4gDdsmbwEOfPVIS0MzQ6%2FQXfPRmeU3KwPYSW3%2BM5UuWJZxBevQqi1i2QiCsyafHYZrxD0OqhZq1bp2GiJv04hX1rWPvtZXO%2BjZSFbGpimyWzzBv9eDJLS%2BrdTU%3D&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: Different countries have different names for *passes*

Comment: @Spork I've seen it used for swimming pools, tanning booths, gym/fitness spaces, internet cafés and other things. They're most common for public transport, but can be applied to other things that are purchased frequently but not necessarily regularly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a prepaid number of miles you can travel on different means of transportation, it can be an electronic version of a  ***[mileage ticket](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mileage+ticket)***:

> - a book (mileage book) or ticket containing coupons good for a certain number of miles of transportation at a fixed rate per mile.

more generally it can be referred to as a  ***prepaid card***:

> - A prepaid card can be used instead of a credit or debit card, but the reason why they can be a great option  is that they are often significantly cheaper.
> - In order to use a prepaid card, you have to load it with money - in many cases this can be done online and you can top it up as and when you need. Once there is money on it you can use your card for purchases or to withdraw cash from an ATM. There is no credit facility however so you can only spend what you have on the card.

Comment: I thought about that but a prepaid card is more like a creditcard, it's equivalent to money. While the 'strippenkaart' is a piece of paper, only to be used for the specific product.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The coffee card in the example can only be used to buy coffee, nothing else. I should have mentioned in the question that 'card' here doesn't mean anything like a credit or debit card, it's more a piece of paper with, for instance, 10 boxes than can be checked on each purchase.

Comment: @Sander_P - I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This Strippenkaart seems very like a **carnet**

> car‧net [countable] 1 British English a small book of tickets that you
>   can use on trains, buses etc - *[Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/carnet)*

Although identified as BrE, it's French in origin. While the English seems to imply the use of a carnet essentially in travelling, it has a more general use in France.

This might mean that the English word **carnet** can't really be used for coffee, etc (although *[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carnet)* does mention it being sold at a discount, which was a feature of the Strippenkaart). On the other hand, Strippenkaart describes something that is not generally available (in Britain, at least), and therefore is unlikely to have a ready-made name, so perhaps, after all, the closest is **carnet**?

Answer (score 0):

My gas station uses a ***"punch card"*** where each punch (hole produced with a hand-held paper puncher) represents a purchased cup of coffee.  After 9 "punches", the 10th cup is free.

Our train system uses a ***"10-ride discount card"*** where a purchase of 10 one-way trips purchased at one time results in an overall discounted price for each ride.

The train system also has a ***"monthly pass"*** which is an unlimited-use discounted fare pass good for a calendar month.

Comment: The '10-ride' discount card seems to be just like what I am talking about (assuming you pay in advance), but is there a more general name for it?

Comment: @Sander_P, I've heard it called a "saver pass" or "super-saver pass" also.

Comment: Also, a "punch card" is not paid for in advance; it allows you to pay as you go. Don

Comment: A Subway Rewards card.

Comment: I think you might be confusing a stamp card with a punch card. Giving a free cup after 9 punches is easy to defraud; just buy your own punch.  Filling up a stamp card with store-specific stamps is trickier. Punch cards  are 'buy 10 for the price of 9, in advance' while stamp cards are 'buy something 9 times, get the 10th for free afterwards'.

Answer (score 0):

**Transpass** and **metro-card** are also common terms for this transportation payment device. They have a magnetic strip or computer chip on which data can be encoded, and can be read by a reader.

If you're asking about cards for purposes other than transportation, they're *prepaid cards* as Josh61 said.

Comment: Please see my updated question and my replay to Josh61

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of *promissory note*. In a game of poker, one player may owe another player a sum of money. He doesn't, however, have the money on his person, so he gives the other player a chit which spells out how much he owes.

In your case, the railway is the "loser," and you're the "winner," since you won X number of trips fairly and squarely (or simply "fair and square") by paying for X number of trips on the railway. The piece of paper you hold as a railway passenger **IS** that promissory note, which the railway pays off one trip at a time. The railway indicates this by marking the chit in a certain way so that eventually the chit is paid off and is torn up!

Answer (score 0):

***Scrip***

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/scrip): a piece of paper that you use temporarily as money

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrip): Scrip (sometimes called chit) is a term for any substitute for legal tender and is often a form of credit. [...] Besides company scrip, other forms of scrip include land scrip, vouchers, token coins such as subway tokens, IOUs, arcade tokens and tickets, and points on some credit cards.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scrip): a certificate to be exchanged for goods, as at a company store

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrip): any of various documents used as evidence that the holder or bearer is entitled to receive something (as a fractional share of stock or an allotment of land)  | paper currency or a token issued for temporary use in an emergency

Note that this usage is rare.